# Finding source code of battery app in settings, Android

Tags: android, battery

I want source code for inbuilt battery app of android, found in settings.

I tried searching github but source available there appears to be pretty outdated.

Please help me in finding that code.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want source code for inbuilt battery app of android, found in settings.

The Settings application can be found here: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings

> I tried searching github but source available there appears to be pretty outdated.

The above repository has been updated in the past two weeks, as of the time of this writing. Anyone who bothers to browse the history for that repository will see that it has been fairly active, with lots of commits. And, looking at the branches, you will see all of the Android releases from Donut to ICS.